# Execute CMD Command by C# winform app?

Tags: c#

I have sample code to run command but its not working ( just opens CMD ) without executing the command

```
string strCmdLine = 
     "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe " +
     "--load-extension=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\toolbar-GC\"";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
process1.Close();
```

where is problem ?

Comment: type with double quote ... """C:\\...

Comment: @codebased: why would OP need a double quote?

Comment: please type full command :) @codebased

Comment: Because you kill it instantly after creation?

Comment: By the way, you should use a [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) string for this.

Comment: no no @OverKiller i cancelled 'process1.close();' and same

Comment: Why are you using the cli for this? you can just call chrome.exe directly using the same method.

Comment: i am loading extension by this command its work in CMD without visual studio

Comment: Btw, why are you using `CMD.exe`? Why not just start `chrome.exe` directly?

Comment: string strCmdLine =
     "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \"";

            var parmaters = "google.com";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strCmdLine, parmaters);

Comment: i am add google chrome extension to chrome programmatic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a /C

Correct syntax for CMD.exe is

> CMD.EXE /c command

```
string strCmdLine = 
     "/C C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe " +
     "--load-extension=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\toolbar-GC\"";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
process1.Close();
```

Comment: but not give me what i need like use in cmd there is something i miss  :S

Comment: @TYT Get rid of process1.Close() or add a wait routine.

Comment: i removed this line !

Comment: It may have to do with the Security Context you are running under

Comment: I do not know. Worth a try. I don't know how chrome's command line works. I don't even know how doing it directly through command line is different versus doing it through C# code. You might wanna do a Console.WriteLine on the command, copy and paste it into a separate CMD window and see if you can duplicate the issue.

Comment: i am using CMD and work fine without visual studio so what is problem !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use cmd.exe mate...

I guess this should do the job for you...

```
 string strCmdLine =
     "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \"";

            var parmaters = "google.com";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strCmdLine, parmaters);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the parameter "/c"

```
string strCmdLine = 
 "/c C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe " +
 "--load-extension=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\toolbar-GC\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
process1.Close();
```